# Tableview methods not working when tableview scrolling disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, delegates

Hy Stack family
I am facing the issue. I put tableview in scroll view with some other subviews. I am making an food ordering app. In which when i scroll up so my collection view will automatically scroll according to my tableview section or either i just select my category from collection view and i want to scroll my tableview at that position so my app user will select that product to order.
Plz help me out how can i handle tableview delegate methods when my main scrollview scrolling!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
                        forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

This method is not working for me when i do scrolling!

Comment: I get a bit confused from your question. You're mentioning scroll view, collection view and also a table view. Are you saying that you're using all of those nested on your screen?

Comment: All delgates set properly?.. Check if `cellForRowAt` at is working while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

1.check your delegate [img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVamo.png) [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1BXi.png) [img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJQoc.png)

2. check your numberRows DataSource return count values (count !=0 )
3. check height of cell

Comment: if not working, will share more solution.